# Converting GMT epoch time to original GMT using python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a rather interesting problem here. Please see below image
[image]

Problem: I am trying to assert the values I get from an API response with Value I fetched from Database.

Value in the response dictionary is :

> '2012-10-10 12:40:06'

Value in the Database is

> 1349858406

which you see in the image and it reads same (GMT)

but when I convert it to human readable using,

```
'created_at': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(db_profile['createddate'])),
```

I get this:

> '2012-10-10 14:10:06'

which is also show in the image.

This fails my test as assert_equal on value fails.
Questions is, How would i get the value which both are same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer to this problem of mine. I converted the queried time to required timezone in my script.

```
def convert_date(self, dt):
        date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
        converted_date_time = date.astimezone(DataGenerator.time_zone_moscow).strftime(
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
return converted_date_time
```